# function overload failed in templated max_element

Tags: c++, boost, overloading

I am confused that why I can't overload "comp" for  `std::max_element(absMcol.begin(), absMcol.end(), comp)` in the following function of `Minvb`.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/io.hpp>

bool comp(double a, double b) {
        return (a < b);
    }

bool comp(boost::numeric::interval<double> a, boost::numeric::interval<double> b) {
    return (a.upper() < b.lower());
}

template<typename T>
void Minvb(T (&x)[2], T M[2][2], T b[2]) {
    T temp1[2];
    int maxrow;
    T l, rhs, temp2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
    std::vector<T> absMcol;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++ i) {
        for(int j = i; j < 2; ++ j) absMcol.push_back(abs(M[j][i]));
        maxrow = std::distance(absMcol.begin(), std::max_element(absMcol.begin(), absMcol.end(), comp) );
        maxrow = maxrow + i;
        absMcol.clear();
    }
}

int main() {
    boost::numeric::interval<double> x[2];
    boost::numeric::interval<double> p11(0.74889637381797358,0.7488963738179738);
    boost::numeric::interval<double> p12(0.1319999952,0.1319999952);
    boost::numeric::interval<double> p21(17.152090001094443,17.152090001094461);
    boost::numeric::interval<double> p22(2.7360000000000002,2.7360000000000002);  
    boost::numeric::interval<double> M[2][2] = {{p11,p12},
                                                {p21,p22}};
    boost::numeric::interval<double> b[2] = {p12,p22};

    double xx[2];
    double pp11=2.7360000000000002;
    double pp12=0.47220448613138766;  
    double pp21=2.011999999999999;  
    double pp22=14.234701687428823;  
    double MM[2][2] = {{pp11,pp12},                                                      
                       {pp21,pp22}};  
    double bb[2] = {pp12,pp22};  
    Minvb(x,M,b);  
    Minvb(xx,MM,bb);

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error report saying:

```
no matching function for call to ‘max_element(std::vector< boost::numeric::interval< double>, std::allocator< boost::numeric::interval< double> > >::iterator,
std::vector< boost::numeric::interval< double>, std::allocator< boost::numeric::interval< double> > >::iterator, < unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

and another error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘max_element(std::vector< double, std::allocator< double> >::iterator, std::vector< double, std::allocator< double> >::iterator, < unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

Deleting

```
bool comp(double a, double b) {
    return (a < b);
}
```

makes the code work but it isn't what I want since I hope the `max_element()` works for both `double` type and `boost::numeric::interval< double>` type.

Noting that I can't overload operator`<` for the `interval` class, where the the `boost::numeric::interval< double>` type data is defined, since I don't want to touch the `<` definition in boost library.Is there anyone can help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: An alternative is to put them in separate `namespace`s, or define `operator<` instead. Also, I'm not sure your second `comp` conforms to the [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Comment: @LogicStuff  I tried to put the comp into a separate `namespace` s and call `std::max_element(absMcol.begin(), absMcol.end(), s::comp)`, it failed. Using functor like  
`class comp { 
public:  
bool operator ()(double a, double b) {return a < b}  }`  
also does not work. I can't overload `operator<` since I don't want to touch the `<` definition in boost library. I wonder whether I did not do what you suggested correctly:(

Comment: [Works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0b91dd1a3dfcc65) and [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec243e937fdb94df).

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry, I should illustrate my problem more clearly. Although in the sample code, the `M[i][j]` passed into `absMcol` is a `boost::numeric::interval< double>` type, what I really hope is `std::vector< T> absMcol` can also be a container for `double`, and `std::vector< double> absMcol` works in `max_element` too. In the main function, `x[4], b[4], M[4][4]` are allowed to be either `double` or `interval< double>`. In both case, `Minvb` should works. Otherwise, designing `Minvb` as a template function does not make much sense.

Comment: @LogicStuff I have edited my question. I think my question is different from the one you suggested, cause I have to explicitly define the `comp` for both `double` and `interval< double>` type data. However, in the suggested duplicated question, they assume that the rule for `fill` function have been implicitly defined for any type data. I wonder whether I can get rid of the "duplicate" label in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @LogicStuff I want to thank you cause I referred to the example you wrote and tried
    `maxrow = std::distance(absMcol.begin(),    

     std::max_element(absMcol.begin(), absMcol.end(), [](T a, T b)    
    
            {
    
                return comp(a, b);

            }));
` and it works finally. Thank you!